# Make link with CamelCase

Tags: python, django

I'm tryin' to create a new page with CamelCase. I'm following a tutorial where they use custom filter to wikify page:

```
from django import template
import re

wikilink = re.compile("\\b([A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+)\\b")
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def wikify(value):
    return wikilink.sub(r"<a href='/wikicamp/\1/'>\1</a>", value)
```

In the turtorial this code should work. I don't get an error, but in my app it only shows this:

> `<a href='/wikicamp/NewPage/'>NewPage</a>`

and not NewPage as a CamelCase 'word'.
Can I do it another way or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: Your question is not clear. How does the actual output differ from the desired output?

Comment: I can edit some text on the page. This text says: This links to a NewPage.
Instead of NewPage is a link it's still a string: This links to a <a href='/wikicamp/NewPage/'>NewPage</a>

Comment: @FSQ it crashes when i use 2 x double qoutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark the output as "safe" for the HTML to be rendered. If you trust any input that could be given to the template filter, and you know it couldn't be malicious, you can do this like so:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe    

@register.filter
def wikify(value):
    output = wikilink.sub(r"<a href='/wikicamp/\1/'>\1</a>", value)
    return mark_safe(output)
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: My apologies. I had teh wrong safe-marking process--the `@register.filter(is_safe=True)` signals that the filter does not add characters that could need to be escaped. You add HTML tags, so that's obviously not true. Instead, see my edited answer above for marking the output safe.